# Mongo - Sum from values in several ref object arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two Mongoose schema/models. One for a `Team` of players and one for the `Players` themselves.

**Team**:

```
// Other less relevant stuff
goalkeepers: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Player'
}],
defenders: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Player'
}],
midfielders: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Player'
}],
attackers: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Player'
}],
points: Number
```

**Player**:

```
// Other less relevant stuff
points: Number
```

The issues is that I need the `Team` points to be the sum of all the points of the `Players` in each position array.

The area I am currently looking into is MongoDB aggregate functions and in particular `$sum` but none of the examples include `ref` objects. The objects would need to be populated first as well so that the points values can be read.

I feel like someone must have come across this problem before but my searches were in vain unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator to do a join on the ref field. But first you'd need create a field that has all the players _id, the best operator to do that would be the **[`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)** operator which takes two or more arrays and returns an array containing the elements that appear in any input array. This is ideal within a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage where you can combine all the array fields with the player refs into one array which you can then **[denormalise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#lookup-unwind-coalescence)**, in preparation for the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** join.

Consider the following aggregation pipeline:

```
Team.aggregate([
  { 
    "$project": {
      "players": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$goalkeepers", 
          "$defenders", 
          "$midfielders", 
          "$attackers"
        ]
      }
    }       
  },
  { "$unwind": "$players" },
  { 
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "players",
      "localField": "players",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "resultingArray"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$resultingArray" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "total": { "$sum": "$resultingArray.points" } 
    }
  }
], function(err, result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just want to say that $lookup requires a newer version of MongoDB. 3.2+ I believe. This would not work on 2.6.2.